# environmentDashboard-Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, environment, dashboard

I have installed the following plugin in Jenkins environmentDashboard(https://plugins.jenkins.io/environment-dashboard/)

Need to incorporate the feature in Jenkinsfile, Sample Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: "branch_name", defaultValue: "master", description: "Enter the branch name")
        string(name: "project_name", defaultValue: "TestAutomation" , description:"BuildWorkspace")
        choice(name: "mach_name", choices: ["LINUX" , "WINDOWS"], description: "OS Selection")        
        string(name: "build_suffix", defaultValue:"", description: "Provide a build suffix name")    
        } 
    environment{
        TARBALL_PATH = ""
        }

    Wrappers{
        environmentDashboard {
            environmentName('Testing')
            componentName('GCC_COMPILER')
            buildNumber({BUILD_ID})
            buildJob({JOB_NAME})
            packageName('TARBALL')
            addColumns(true)
            columns('RESULT', 'PASS')
        }
    }    
    stages {
        stage('TARBALL GENERATION') {            
            steps {                
                script{
                buildName "${mach_name}#${BUILD_NUMBER}"
                buildDescription "${mach_name} Test Execution on ${NODE_NAME}"
                }                
                echo "Branch name is ${params.branch_name}"
                echo "Preferred MACH: ${params.mach_name}"                
                echo "Reached Here after printing selected parameters"            
                sh """
                    #!/bin/bash
                    echo "Multiline shell steps execution"
                    printenv | sort
                """
            } //steps
        } //stage
    }//Stages
}//pipeline
```

Getting the error as follows:

Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 13: Undefined section "Wrappers" @ line 13, column 5.
       Wrappers{
       ^

1 error

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:327)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)
```

Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Did you take a look at `line 13, column 5` in your script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write wrappers in lowercase.

Like `wrappers{}`
Not `Wrappers{}`

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but post changing Wrappers to wrappers(lowercase), I'm still seeing the error.

Answer (score 0):

For pipeline job you need to use the following code:

```
environmentDashboard(addColumns: false, buildJob: '', buildNumber: 'Version-1', componentName: 'WebApp-1', data: [], nameOfEnv: 'Environment-1', packageName: '') {
    // some block
}
```

In fact, you can skip `// some block` and just use `{}`. That worked for me.